# ESS: getting help on package

Tags: ess, r

Is it possible to get ESS to display results of `help(package=xxx)` in a new buffer, like it does for `?xxx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`M-x ess-display-package-index`, bound to `C-c C-d i` by default, does exactly this.